# Yes/No message box using QMessageBox

Tags: c++, qt

I want to close the application when I click "Yes", but it closes even I press "No". What is wrong?

```
void secondwindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox msg;
    msg.setWindowTitle("Quit");
    msg.setText("Are you sure you want to quit?");
    msg.setIcon(QMessageBox::Question);
    msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::No);
    msg.setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("background-color: white;"));
    if(msg.exec()==QMessageBox::Yes){
        QApplication::quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: when you are referring to "it" do you mean that the QMessageBox closes, or the application? The QMessageBox will close when one of the buttons are pressed, that's just how it behaves.

Comment: the application closes,that's the problem

Comment: I've just tested this code (Qt 6.4.1) and it works as expected. Cannot reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can check `msg.result()` code:

```
// if(msg.exec()==QMessageBox::Yes){
//     QApplication::quit();
// }

msg.exec();
if (msg.result() == QMessageBox::Yes){
    QApplication::quit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
    void secondwindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
            QMessageBox msg;
            msg.setWindowTitle("Quit");
            msg.setText("Are you sure you want to quit?");
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox::Question);
            msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::No);
            msg.setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("background-color: white;"));
            int answer=msg.exec();
            switch (answer) {
            case QMessageBox::Yes:
                 QApplication::quit();
                 break;
            case QMessageBox::No:
                 //do something
                 break;
           }
}
```